# Why is adding more layers making my neutral network worse?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm kinda confused ... I first started with:

```
model = Sequential()    # (32, 32, 3)
model.add(Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) 
model.add(Dropout(0.25)) 

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

and two more models with one extra block of `Conv2D, Conv2D, MaxPool, Dropout` with 16 and 32 conv filters in model2 and two extra blocks with 16, 32, 64, 128, conv filters in model3.
I got max accuracy of about 75%, 78%, 82% respectively ...

then I changed the number of filters in Conv2D in the first model to 16 and 32, and number of nodes in the flat layer to 300, and got accuracy of 97%.
However, changing models 2 and 3, which are essentially the same as model 1, but with more layers, didn't improve accuracy and actually made it worse... I tried different numbers of filters in the extra Conv layers and different numbers of nodes in the flat layer, from 300 to 1500, but nothing seems to make a difference. No matter what, the first model, with the least number of layers seems to be doing the best.

Why is that?

Comment: Larger search space, more parameters to learn. Therefore the learners will take even more time to learn and face more local optima, saddle points, plateaus etc.

Comment: @phoxis, ok, but would the models with more layers do better overall with more iterations maybe? I did 40 for all three on the first run and got those accuracies and only 10 after changing the first model since it was doing so well so fast. So are they just learning slower but would actually do better eventually? Or not really? >.>

Comment: You need to use a validation set (or crossvalidation), which I assume you are using, to get the estimated accuracy. It is not necessary that more layers get better results. If the model is complex then it will tend to over fit, therefore you get poor results for the test set, or on new data. Also, increasing the number of datapoints can help, and the number of iterations as well

Comment: When keeping everything else constant, a bigger network has more *capabilities*, but that can also be a bad thing (and usually needs not only more time, but also more data). The more capable a network is (less a-priori assumptions), the more it's prone to overfitting in general.

Comment: @sascha, oh ok, yeah the more complex models being more inclined to overfit makes sense.